# Loading images in java (eclipse vs IntelliJ)

Tags: java, eclipse, image, intellij-idea

One would load an image:
 
project>res>img.png (path = "res/img.png")

```
BufferedImage image = loadImage(path);
```

Where LoadImage is:

```
protected BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("could not load: " + path);
    }
    return img;
}
```

Someone using Eclipse used:
 
(path = "/img.png")

```
BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(Sprite.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But using this in IntelliJ gives:

> Exception in thread "Game_main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   input == null!

why getResourceAsStream fails?

Answer (score 0):

`getResourceAsStream()` uses (by default) the system classloader to find the file. Therefore, the resources directory has to be on the classpath - check that the IntelliJ project is correctly including the `res` directory and marking it as a resource directory.